# Not getting expected results from a ListChangeListener on a TreeView selection model

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, changelistener, selectionmodel

I have the following test code below:

```java
    tvNodes.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    tvNodes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TreeItem<Node>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends TreeItem<Node>> c) {
                    while (c.next()) {
                        log.debug("From {} To {} (Removed: {}, Added: {}, Replaced: {}, List: {})", c.getFrom(), c.getTo(), c.wasRemoved(), c.wasAdded(), c.wasReplaced(), c.getList());
                        if (c.wasAdded()) {
                            for (var added : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                                log.debug("\tADDED ITEM: {}", added);
                            }
                        }
                        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                            for (var removed : c.getRemoved()) {
                                log.debug("\tREMOVED ITEM: {} ({})", removed.getValue(), c.getRemovedSize());
                            }
                        }
                        if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                            log.debug("\tWAS REPLACED {} to {}", c.getFrom(), c.getTo());
                        }
                        if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                            log.debug("\tWAS PERMUTATED {} to {}", c.getFrom(), c.getTo());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

When transitioning from a "full selection" to a "single item selection" (Circle 8)

From:

[image: Full Selection]

To:

[image: Single Selection]

I expected to receive two change events (Remove). The first event returns items from **Circle (3)** to **Circle (7)** and the second event returns items from **Circle (9)** to **Circle (11)**.

**Actual Results**:

The first event returns the first half as expected, but the second event returns items **4,5,6** instead of **9, 10 and 11**.

```
From 0 To 0 (Removed: true, Added: false, Replaced: false, List: [TreeItem [ value: Circle (8) ]])
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (3) (5)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (4) (5)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (5) (5)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (6) (5)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (7) (5)
From 1 To 1 (Removed: true, Added: false, Replaced: false, List: [TreeItem [ value: Circle (8) ]])
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (4) (3)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (5) (3)
    REMOVED ITEM: Circle (6) (3)
```

Is this a bug or am processing the results incorrectly? I'm currently using JDK 15.0.036 with OpenJFX 15

Comment: your expectation is correct, afaics - you might consider reporting a bug (yet another or maybe it's already known .. could be related to https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/353)

Comment: would you happen to know how I could create an account in bugs.openjdk.java.net? I cannot seem to find any info about it on their page.

Comment: hmm .. don't think that you need an account, it's the same as for every java bug: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/